# If Else Statement -- 'If' operator requires either two or three operands

Tags: .net, vb.net, gridview

**Aim:** To show comments, but limit to 25 characters plus 3 dots. The dots would only show if over 25 characters. In addition we would show a tooltip so the user can see the full text if required.

I have tried with and without the tooltip. There's no error in Visual Studio just on the website.

**Issue:**  'If' operator requires either two or three operands.

**Code:**

```
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Recommendations" SortExpression="Recommendations">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblRecommendations" runat="server" Text='<%# If(Len(Eval("Recommendations").ToString()) > 25, Left(Eval("Recommendations").ToString(), 25) + "...", Eval("Recommendations").ToString() %>' ToolTip='<%# Eval("Recommendations") %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

**Notes:**

I have some working If statements already which work such as the below so assume I have a comma or bracket misplaced?;

```
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Next Survey Due" SortExpression="NEXTSURVEYDUE">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblNEXTSURVEYDUE" runat="server" Text='<%# If(Eval("NEXTSURVEYDUE", "{0:d}") = "01/01/1900", " ", Eval("NEXTSURVEYDUE", "{0:d}")) %>' />
                       </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Fix was as per @Richard states add a ")" to the end

Comment: If you suspect misplaced commas or brackets, it's usually a better use of everyone's time for you to try to isolate that yourself. One trick I use is to open a blank text file, copy in the expression, and then separate everything out onto multiple lines - every time you hit a `(`, move to a new line and increase the indent. Every time you hit a comma, move to a new line, and every time you hit a `)`, move to a new line and decrease the indent. Usually extra or missing elements will jump out at you.

Comment: Nice idea about multiple lines. For the record I looked over it, went out, came back, still could not see the error and thus asked. Second pair of eyes sometimes! :-) Plus added bonus of shorter way of doing "..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Text code as listed in your question is missing a closing bracket:

```
If(Len(Eval("Recommendations").ToString()) > 25, Left(Eval("Recommendations").ToString(), 25) + "...", Eval("Recommendations").ToString()
```

As a side-note, you should use the &hellip; (…) HTML entity instead of 3 dots, it only takes a single character and usually takes up less space.